# Specifying pattern for JEST to run everything BUT tests named

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

Using JEST v21.2.1

Jest Config:

```
"jest": {
        "preset": "jest-puppeteer",
        "testURL": "http://localhost",
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
            "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
            "@ecster/ecster-net": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/ecster-net.js"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.(js|jsx)",
            "!src/knockout-components/**/*.(js|jsx)"
        ],
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ],
        "testResultsProcessor": "jest-teamcity-reporter"
    },
```

I need to have a separate NPM script that runs different tests.

One script runs ONLY my End2End tests:

```
jest __e2e__
```

The other should run everything BUT the **e2e** tests.

This is what I have - but it isn't working (runs all tests)

```
jest (?!^__e2e__$)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line option [testPathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-array-string), like so:

```
jest --testPathIgnorePatterns=__e2e__
```

Comment: Glad to help!